# Unable to copy files to and from s3 from vpc server: "Unable to locate credentials"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'd like to copy files to/from an s3 bucket from servers on my vpc without having to add credentials to each server in my cloud.

I followed the instructions at https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-private-connection-no-authentication/ to set up a policy for a newly created VPC endpoint. As far as I can tell, I did everything correctly and added a good bucket policy to my bucket. I double checked the routing table settings. All appears good.

But perhaps I don't understand what this is supposed to do. When I type in:

`aws s3 cp s3://My_Bucket_Name/some.pdf .`

I just get:

`fatal error: Unable to locate credentials`

from my server in the vpc.

Here is the anonymized bucket policy I have:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy232323232323",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1607462615603",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567789:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceVpce": "vpce-123456c789"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending: `--no-sign-request`

From [Command line options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html):

> A Boolean switch that disables signing the HTTP requests to the AWS service endpoint. This prevents credentials from being loaded.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it did the trick. Though I'm now getting `fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden` The bucket policy looks correct to me. I've triple checked it.

Comment: OK, getting closer still. I changed the value for Principal to "*" like in the example on amazon instead of using the policy generator. I can now download but I get access denied when uploading: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied` Weird because it's definitely in my policy.

Comment: What commands are you sending with the PutObject? Are you setting an ACL? If so, it might clash with the S3 Block Public Access settings.

Comment: Nice option. Do you know if this is only useful for anonymous access to S3 using CLI?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I figured it out. I had to uncheck "Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)".

Comment: @Marcin, I'm the wrong guy to ask as I'm pretty new to ec2. I was just looking for an easier way to transfer files between servers without the mess of dealing with ssh keys. I found this option after doing some googling.